# Get absolute path of favicon and verify that it's an image

Tags: php

I have a list of links that is dynamically populated and I would like each link to have its favicon displayed next to it. Thanks to some others here I'm slightly closer to getting this working but the issues I'm still having are that  since the code below is pulling whatever it finds that matches the search, in some cases it gets the relative path of the favicon and in other cases, as I've mind-numbingly discovered, it's getting something completely random, like a script that completely messes up my page and sends me on a wild goose chase through my error logs.

So my question is: How can I get the absolute path of the favicon, and if I can modify the code below to do that, then how can I also verify that whatever it's finding in the search is actually an image?

**The function that searches for the favicon link:**

```
// Get favicon of link
function get_favicon($url) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->strictErrorChecking = FALSE;
    $doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));
    $xml = simplexml_import_dom($doc);
    $arr = $xml->xpath('//link[@rel="shortcut icon"]');
    $favicon = $arr[0]['href'];
    return $favicon;        
}
```

**The code from the display page, which pulls the URL from an array inside a foreach loop:**

```
$ll_favicon = get_favicon(esc_attr( $ll_entry['ll_url'] ));
echo '<img src="'.$ll_favicon.'" />';
```

Thanks for your help!

---

**UPDATE:**

Good grief, this is crazy. I've been researching this all day and still no luck.

At the moment it works (but takes forever to load) exactly 50% of the time. Yes, 50%. It will load after a while and work perfectly, and then I will refresh the page without changing a single thing and it'll break again (the page only loads up to the same link), and then I'll refresh and it'll work, and then refresh again and it won't, and now I'm incredibly frustrated and I'm giving up. It always breaks just before the same link: http://www.santafenewmexican.com/pasatiempo/

It's just that link. I've even tried it like this and it breaks the page wherever I put it, yet works fine with any other URL:

```
<?php echo get_favicon('http://www.santafenewmexican.com/pasatiempo/'); ?>
```

Here's the function I ended up with. If anyone wants to see if they can get this working, by all means please have at it:

```
// Get favicon of link
function get_favicon($url) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->strictErrorChecking = FALSE;
    $doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));
    $xml = simplexml_import_dom($doc);
    $arr = $xml->xpath('//link[@rel="shortcut icon"]');
    $favicon = $arr[0]['href'];
    if( !empty($favicon) ) {

        // Verify that the URL is the absolute path:
        if(strpos($favicon,'http') !== 0  && strpos($favicon,'//') !== 0 && strpos($favicon,'://') !== 0)
                $favicon = rtrim($url,'/') . $favicon;

        // Verify that the file found actually exists and if so, whether it's an image:
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$favicon);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        if(curl_exec($ch)!==FALSE)
        {
            if(function_exists('finfo_fopen')) {
                // for PHP 4:
                $fhandle = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME);
                $mime_type = finfo_file($fhandle,$favicon);
                // for PHP 5:
                $file_info = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
                $mime_type = $file_info->buffer(file_get_contents($favicon));

                switch($mime_type) {
                    case ('image/x-icon'||'image/icon'||'image/vnd.microsoft.icon'||'image/gif'||'image/jpeg'||'image/png'||'image/vnd.sealed-png'||'image/vnd.sealedmedia.softseal-gif'||'image/vnd.sealedmedia.softseal-jpg'):
                        return $favicon;
                }
            } elseif(function_exists('exif_imagetype')) {
               if (exif_imagetype($favicon) != (IMAGETYPE_GIF || IMAGETYPE_JPEG || IMAGETYPE_PNG || IMAGETYPE_ICO)) {
                    return 'No, exif_imagetype did not return a valid mime.';
                } else {
                    return $favicon;
                }
            } elseif(function_exists('getimagesize')) {

                $imginfo_array = getimagesize($favicon);

                if ($imginfo_array !== false) {
                    $mime_type = $imginfo_array['mime'];
                    switch($mime_type) { 

                    case ('image/x-icon'||'image/icon'||'image/vnd.microsoft.icon'||'image/gif'||'image/jpeg'||'image/png'||'image/vnd.sealed-png'||'image/vnd.sealedmedia.softseal-gif'||'image/vnd.sealedmedia.softseal-jpg'):
                        return $favicon;
                    }
                } else {
                    return 'No, getimagesize did not return a valid mime.';
                }
            }
        } else {
            return 'This file does not exist!';
        }
    } else {
        return 'No favicon was found.';
    }
}
```

Comment: As to why it takes long to load my guess would be that it makes a lot of network requests. You're re-downloading the favicon over and over again. Basically every time you use a url where php function expects a file path, but also when you manually fetch it with curl. Better approach would be to download it once, store to a temporary file and then run the checks on local copy.

Comment: Storing a local copy is also beneficial because you don't have to fetch the file every time your page is loaded. If you can correlate the url to the local image file, you can use the local file instead of going to the site to fetch it. And if you use the image url you echo relative to your site, the client browser won't have to resolve all those domain names when it loads the page. This increases perceived page performance.

Comment: Thanks @weirdan - I suspected as much but I'm not sure how I would download the image and then perform all the checks, since if it's not an image I wouldn't want to download it. Realistically the only reason I've gone through all this is because of that one problem link - in most other cases if it's correctly finding the favicon, of course it'll be an image file so I wouldn't need to do all this, but it seems like the code that finds the favicon url isn't foolproof enough. I may come back to this but for now, maybe it'll help someone else.

Comment: «I'm not sure how I would download the image and then perform all the checks» –  `$data = file_get_contents($url); $localname = tempnam('/tmp', 'fav'); file_put_contents($localname, $data); // then use $localname where you would use the $url, unlink($localname) when you don't need it anymore`

«since if it's not an image I wouldn't want to download it.» – But you can't know if it's an image unless you download it (even if you only store it in memory). `finfo()` functions have to work on the file data, and to get that to your server you have to go and request it from the remote server.

Answer (score 1):

You should check `href` and see it's absolute or not.

Here is an example

```
$favicon = $arr[0]['href'];
if(strpos($favicon,'http') !== 0  && strpos($favicon,'//') !== 0 && strpos($favicon,'://') !== 0)
    $favicon = rtrim($url,'/') . '/' . $favicon;
return $favicon;
```

Comment: Thanks @CooPer! I had to remove the `.'/'` after the rtrim because the relative URLs already had a slash. This got me a little closer but unfortunately I still can't figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: @Shoelaced what is wrong after this code ? you should use `ltrim` for `$favicon` and add `.'/'` to make sure you have a single `/` not double.